# Clustered data and the Friedman test

Tags: kruskal-wallis-test, cluster-sample, friedman-test

Good morning, I am performing a risk factor analysis of the individual and household-level factors associated with *Plasmodium* infection in individuals located in 8 villages in Cambodia.

I have established the prevalence of infection at the village level. I want to perform an initial statistical test to determine if there are significant differences in village-level prevalence.

In other papers, I have seen the Kruskal-Wallis test used, yet that assumes independence, which is violated when I have clustered data. Reading around the subject, I have seen suggestions that the Friedman test might be appropriate in this situation, for that does not assume independence.

Is that approach applicable to my situation?

Thank you for taking the time to read and hopefully respond to my query.